# Proof of Coppel's Inequality for the matrix "measure".

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, reference-works, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the matrix measured proposed by W. Coppel in "Stability and Asymptotic Behavior of Differential Equations" in 1965, but I cannot find a pdf of this paper online, so if anyone can help me find this, that would be awesome. These are the main questions:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Define $$\mu(A) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{||\mathbb{1} + \epsilon A|| - 1}{\epsilon}$$
Where $\mathbb{1}$ denotes the identity matrix.

Show that:
$$||e^{At}|| \le e^{\mu(A)t}$$

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: That's confusing - a measure is usually defined on sets, not individual elements of a set.

Comment: In particular, $\emptyset$ is not in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, so $\mu$ is not defined on it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The measure in this case is defined on a matrix, not a set. I have edited the post to clarify.

Comment: The meaning of the word "measure" used by the author is not related to the standard definition of measure theory. He does not give a precise definition, but he calls $\mu$ a "measure" because it is not a genuine norm. Rather, $\mu$ is subadditive and positively homogeneous, which means it is a [sublinear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function).